# Pandas Duplicate() return all duplicates one time except one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am trying to get all the Nobel prize winners that won more than once since 1901 - 2016. I tried pandas `duplicate()` method but it return all the duplicates once except the one row or item. I am getting duplicates based on `full_name` column in DataFrame. I have tried different combinations of parameters but got the same result. I know I can remove that one row manually, but what is happening wrong here. My code is given as

Try-1

```
lucky_winners = df[df.duplicated(['full_name'])]
```

Try-2

```
lucky_winners = df[df.duplicated(['full_name'], keep='first')]
```

Try-3

```
lucky_winners = df[df.duplicated(['full_name'], keep='last')]
```

Same OutPut:

```
lucky_winners.full_name

62                           Marie Curie, née Sklodowska
215    Comité international de la Croix Rouge (Intern...
340                                   Linus Carl Pauling
348    Comité international de la Croix Rouge (Intern...
424                                         John Bardeen
505                                     Frederick Sanger
523    Office of the United Nations High Commissioner...
```

The duplicated entity is `Comité international de la Croix Rouge (International Committee of the Red Cross)`. I even checked them for Boolean Comparison and get `True`. Checked it using

```
lucky_winners.iloc[1].full_name == lucky_winners.iloc[3].full_name
```

I can't get that where is the actual problem.

Comment: @Ben.T Sorry for that. I edited the question and put the output again there. Kindly review it again

Comment: `df.duplicated` returns True if the row IS a duplicate.  So, if a name occurs 4 times, you'll get one False and three Trues.  You're keeping the Trues.  I think you want the inverse of what you're doing.

Comment: @TimRoberts Okay! I think this method won't work here and I should try something else. Thanks

Comment: @TimRoberts And what can I do if I want to keep all the duplicates for only once?

Comment: Maybe `pd.unique(df[df.duplicated(['full_name'])])`?

Comment: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (7,21) into shape (7)
But I resolved the issue using this 

`lucky_winners = (df[df.duplicated(['full_name'])])
lucky_winners.drop_duplicates(subset = ["full_name"], inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did to get all the duplicates without repetition is that (Go read the question again first):

- Got all the duplicates that has more than one occurrences

  `lucky_winners = df[df.duplicated(['full_name'])]`
- Then drop the duplicates from this newly created DataFrame

  `lucky_winners.drop_duplicates(subset = ['full_name'], inplace=True)`

That's all! In this way I got all the duplicate rows without repetition

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for all unique values with more than one occurrence, one way to do this is with [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the optional `return_counts=True` argument. The resulting tuple `(unique, counts)`  can be used in combination to find all unique values with counts over 1:

```py
In [3]: # mash keys to get a series with repeated values
   ...: s = pd.Series(list('abcoiansfaionawiaonwncawowc'))

In [4]: # get unique values and counts
   ...: u, c = np.unique(s, return_counts=True)

In [5]: # find all unique keys with occurrence counts > 1
   ...: u[c > 1]
Out[5]: array(['a', 'c', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'w'], dtype=object)
```